# EditText focus tracking and deleting

Tags: android

I have three EditBoxes what is the best way to set the next focus after a digit was entered in one box and then what is the best way to track deleting (going backwards) from box3 to box2 and then to box1, or from box3, to box2 and then be able if i attempt to enter something  to box3, focus it and enter the new number on box3 if box2 already has something.

I want to start with this question which is much simpler that what i had posted here: (You can see what i am trying there but i think if I get the basic idea I may be able to pull it off).

[posting with details for issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625765/android-using-fragments-with-edittext-boxes)

I am just having a big issue using two different things, OnkeyListener for deleting and TextWatch for inputing, I can't seem to get it right. New to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am giving you one simple example which has 3 Editbox that shows Mobile Number respectivly 3,3,4 digits to each editbox & change the focus.

Xml

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtxt_phonenumber_one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_1"
                android:ems="3"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtxt_phonenumber_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_1"
                android:ems="3"
                 android:maxLength="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtxt_phonenumber_three"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_1"
                android:ems="4"
                 android:maxLength="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Class

```
//Initialize 3 of EditBox.

// Rest of te code

edtxt_phonenumber1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (s.length() > 2) {
                    edtxt_phonenumber2.requestFocus();
                }
                            if (s.length()==0) {
                //previoue_box.requestFocus();
            }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }
        });

        edtxt_phonenumber2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() > 2) {
                    edtxt_phonenumber3.requestFocus();
                }
                            if (s.length()==0) {
                edtxt_phonenumber1.requestFocus();
            }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {


            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }
        });
        edtxt_phonenumber3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() > 3) {
                    edtxt_email.requestFocus();
                }
                            if (s.length()==0) {
                edtxt_phonenumber2.requestFocus();
            }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {


            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {


            }
        });
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: rhanks, how about if i am deleting and i finished deleting on editbox #3, how do i make it to setFocus to the second (middle EditText)